# R:Looking for advice for optimise Backward selection algorithm

Tags: r

I am trying to optimise a little algorithm that I've made to perform Backward Selection in the field of Spline regression.
Basically what the algorithm do is :

Take `k` a vector of knots with `n` components.

Eliminate the i-th component , `i=1,...,n`.

Estimate a spline regression using the knot vector `k[-i]`, `i=1,...,n`.

Select the one with smaller Residual Sum of Squares (`RSS`), and estimate the BIC for that model.

Let `k=k[-which.min(RSS)]`.

Start the algorithm again until `n=1`.

My code is

```
library(splines)
prune<-function(K,y0,x,deg=3){
  KNOTS<-matrix(nrow = (length(K)),ncol=(length(K)-1))
  y<-y0
  BIC<-vector(length =(length(K)-1) )

  for(j in 1:(length(K)-1)){
    RSS<-vector(1:(length(K)))
    {for(i in 1:(length(K)))
      RSS[i]<-sum((y-lm(y~bs(x,knots = K[-i],Boundary.knots = c(min(x),max(x)),degree = deg,intercept = T)-1)$fitted.values)^2)
    }
    K<-K[-which.min(RSS)]
    for (k in 1:(length(K)))
      KNOTS[k,j]<-K[k]

    BIC[j]<-BIC(lm(y~bs(x,knots = K,Boundary.knots = c(min(x),max(x)),degree = deg,intercept = T)-1))
  }

  KSTAR<-as.vector(KNOTS[, which.min(BIC)])
  I<-which.min(BIC)
  KSTAR<-na.omit(KSTAR)  
  return(list(KSTAR,KNOTS,I))
}
```

where `K` is the knot vector, `y0` is the dependent variable, `x` is the independent variable and `deg` is the degree of the B-splines.
The problem is that when I have many observations, lets say 5000 or 10000 it takes too much to compute the output.

My R programming skills are quite elementary and probably there are things that could be written in another way in order to increase the speed.

Could you please give me some advice?

I've been reading some blogs about speeding up R code, but honestly I don't see how I could apply things like pre-allocation, vectorization, etc.

for an example one could start with

```
x=(0:4000)/4000  
y=sin(4*x)+2*exp(-30*(4*x)^2)+rnorm(4000,0,0.1)
K=seq(0,4000,by=100)
```

> I am not asking you to do my job, just looking for some advice
>   regarding the structure of the algorithm. Thanks in advance!

Comment: While code can definitely be optimised, do you really want to "re-invent" it? Have a look at MARS algorithm, maybe it would be a better way to go?

Comment: Also error statistics (RSS) on cross-validated (or just validation) set might be more robust selection method than RSS/BIC in-sample.

Comment: Actually I was replicating the results of an author that uses this particular methodology, that's why I wanted to optimise it rather than changing the method. Anyway I'll consider changing the selection method on my own algorithm, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bulk of the time taken in your code is by the repeated `lm` calls. Thiscan be seen if you try:

```
N <- 4000
x=(0:N)/N
y=sin(4*x)+2*exp(-30*(4*x)^2)+rnorm(N+1,0,0.1)
K=seq(0,N,by=100)
library(profvis)
profvis(prune1(K,x,y))
```

If you break down the function call,

```
lm(y~bs(x,knots = K[-i],Boundary.knots = c(min(x),max(x)),degree = deg,intercept = T)-1)
```

as :

```
x1 <- bs(x,knots = K,degree = 3,intercept = T)
  lmod <- lm(y~x1-1)
```

The output of `bs`, `x1` only has values in the first few columns. The rest are all zero. Also, since you don't really need the extra details provided by `lm`, you can further strip it down to the essentials. Once you do that, your function will be much faster:

```
library(rbenchmark)
library(MASS)
benchmark(a={
  x1 <- bs(x,knots = K,degree = 3,intercept = T)
  lmod <- lm(y~x1-1)
  RSS<-sum(lmod$residuals**2)
},
b={
  x1 <- bs(x,knots = K,degree = 3,intercept = T)
  x2 <- x1[,which(colSums(abs(x1))>0)]   # Removing zero columns
  x21 <- ginv(x2)            # Simplified lm. If you don't want to risk it,
  y1 <- x2 %*%(x21  %*% y)   # you can try: lmod <- lm(y~x2-1)
  RSS <- sum((y-y1)^2)       #              RSS<-sum(lmod$residuals**2)
},replications = 9)          
#   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1    a            9   0.187    5.054     0.171    0.016          0         0
# 2    b            9   0.037    1.000     0.036    0.000          0         0
all.equal(lmod$residuals,as.numeric(y-y1),check.attributes = F)
# [1] TRUE
```

It should be even faster for larger sizes of data.
Your final function would look something like:

```
prune1<-function(K,y0,x,deg=3){
  KNOTS<-matrix(nrow = (length(K)),ncol=(length(K)-1))
  y<-y0
  BIC<-numeric(length =(length(K)-1) )
  kmin <- 0
  for(j in 1:(length(K)-1)){
    min_rss=Inf
    for(i in 1:(length(K))){
      x1 <- bs(x,knots = K,degree = 3,intercept = T)
      x2 <- x1[,which(colSums(abs(x1))>0)]
      x21 <- ginv(x2)
      y1 <- x2 %*%(x21  %*% y)
      RSS <- sum((y-y1)^2)
      if(RSS<min_rss){
        min_rss <- RSS
        kmin <- i
      }
    }
    K<-K[-kmin]
    KNOTS[1:length(K),j]<-K
    x1 <- bs(x,knots = K,degree = deg,intercept = T)
    x2 <- x1[,which(colSums(abs(x1))>0)]
    lmod <- lm(y~x2-1)
    BIC[j]<-BIC(lmod)
  }

  KSTAR<-as.vector(KNOTS[, which.min(BIC)])
  I<-which.min(BIC)
  KSTAR<-na.omit(KSTAR)  
  return(list(KSTAR,KNOTS,I))
}

benchmark(a={l <- prune(K,y,x)},
          b={l1 <- prune1(K,y,x)},
          replications = 1)
# test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1    a            1  15.480    3.091    15.483        0          0         0
# 2    b            1   5.008    1.000     5.008        0          0         0
```

I also tried out the function for 10,000 observations and 100 knots and got a runtimeof 3 minutes